# How do I get a Netgear N900 WNDA4100 wireless USB adapter working?

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem, netgear

From what I can tell there is no Linux support for the Netgear N900 WNDA4100. Ndiswrapper doesn't support this, either. I tried installing the driver in wine and the installer crashes. How do I go about requesting support for this device? Is it not possible, or is it just that no one has requested support for this device yet? I was trying to read stuff about compiling drivers myself but this is way way out of my league. 
Unfortunately I have no other option besides using my Android phone in USB Tether mode while connected to my network via wifi. Through some miracle, Ubuntu sees it as a wired connection. But, this is not an ideal situation.

http://www.netgear.com/home/products/wireless-adapters/ultimate-wireless-adapters/WNDA4100.aspx

http://www.wikidevi.com/wiki/Netgear_WNDA4100

Answer (score 3):

A fellow on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11893835) thinks it's the `2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1.tar.bz2` that will work for that stick.

I can't test it, but it compiles fine for me.

I started with [this](http://en.sourceforge.jp/frs/g_redir.php?m=jaist&f=%2Fspaze%2FSources%2F2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1.tar.bz2) driver from Sourceforge Japan.

Working along with [this guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-install-rt2870-chipset-based-usb-wireless-adapter.html) I changed these lines:

```
HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=n
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=n
```

to this:

```
HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
```

I applied this fix for a change since the driver was written as directed in an edit [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11893835):

```
make clean
find . -name \*.[ch] -exec grep usb_buffer_alloc "{}" ";" -exec sed -i 's/usb_buffer_alloc/usb_alloc_coherent/g' "{}" ";"
find . -name \*.[ch] -exec grep usb_buffer_free "{}" ";" -exec sed -i 's/usb_buffer_free/usb_free_coherent/g' "{}" ";"
```

Then `make` and it builds fine.

`sudo make install` also went without errors.

The rest of [this guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-install-rt2870-chipset-based-usb-wireless-adapter.html) seems sound, but again...I don't have one to test.

The dead link for 'get the latest firmware' should point [here](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/support.php?sn=501).